# Unable to Except cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken Error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, cryptography

I tried this:

```
from cryptography import *
try:
    #code here to create key from a password
    f=Fernet(key)
    token=f.decrypt(data)
except cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken:
    print("wow")
```

but it still raises Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.decrypt):

> decrypt(token, ttl=None)
>
> Raises:
>
> - cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken – If the token is in any way    invalid, this exception is raised. A token may be invalid for a
>     number of reasons: it is older than the ttl, it is malformed, or it
>     does not have a valid signature.
> - TypeError – This exception is raised if token is not bytes.

You should use:

```
from cryptography import *
import cryptography

try:
    #code here to create key from a password
    f=Fernet(key)
    token=f.decrypt(data)
except (cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken, TypeError):
    print("wow")
```

also, the `key` should be bytes – A URL-safe base64-encoded 32-byte key.

---

if you have the following error message:

```
Error: Incorrect padding
```

this is generated because in the `Fernet` class the constructor  it is applying a `base64.decodestring` against your `key`

```
key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)
```

to catch the error you can use:

```
from binascii import Error
from cryptography import *
import cryptography

try:
    #code here to create key from a password
    f=Fernet(key)
    token=f.decrypt(data)
except (cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken, TypeError, Error):
    print("wow")
```

Comment: It says `NameError: name 'cryptography' is not defined`

Comment: @Mr.Dark because you didn't import `cryptography` try now my answer

Comment: i have a doubt in tkinter. how do i chat with you?

Comment: if you have another issue the best is to write another question, thx! have a nice day!